# Up-voted posts in “First Posts” review tool

Tags: feature-request, voting, review-page

When using the new review tool for first posts, I came across some questions, that I already up-voted before. So in essence I already did review them.

That means either they should not appear in the review tool at all, or I should at least be able to say “I'm done” after having a second look. Don’t you agree?

Comment: This was already the case with the previous reviewing tools, so it has pretty much just rolled over to the newer interface. I would agree with you. There is a badge associated with reviewing, called the [silver Reviewer badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/128/reviewer) and I guess there must be some action initiated for "actual review", before it could be considered part of your "review tally". Additionally, reviews are only available for the first couple of reviewers.